# error message with this line

Tags: c++

Why do i get this error message?

```
Error: expected a ';'
```

from:

```
int main()
{
    int score;
    double distance;
    char playAgain;
    bool shieldsUp;

    short lives;
    short aliensKilled;

    score = 0
    distance = 1200.76;
    playAgain = 'y';
    shieldsUp = true;
    lives = 3
    aliensKilled = 10;
```

the error is under `distance = 1200.76;` and `aliensKilled = 10;`,

Comment: u know, a missing semicolon... look up one line. however, if you're hiding from an enemy then don't rely on people forgetting to look up: often the best hiding place is then down on the ground (just a tip).

Comment: Please buy a [book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read it!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
score = 0
```

You want:

```
score = 0;
```

Similar for `lives = 3`

Answer (score 1):

You really forgot something:

```
...
score = 0;
...
lives = 3;
...
```